# how to fill color in line_strips in openGL, not in the line?

Tags: opengl, graphics

i have drawn two parabola to make a bowl.But i want to fill up their color.But they are in line strips.If i color them only lines are colored.But i want that the overlapped area also be colored

Comment: Don't draw `LINE_STRIP` when you don't want to draw lines then. Use `GL_POLYGON` or if possible triangles.

Answer (score 2):

There are different types of primitives in OGL:

- `GL_POINTS`: draws points
- `GL_LINES`, `GL_LINE_STRIP`, `GL_LINE_LOOP`: draws lines
- `GL_TRIANGLES`, `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`, `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`, `GL_QUADS`, `GL_QUAD_STRIP`, and `GL_POLYGON`:
  draws filled polygons (triangles, quads and polygons).

See the OGL documentation of Khronos group: [Primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive)